# Where is located physical directory of my IIS Express site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

In which directory IIS Express stores my site DLLs and other resources?

I have examined the `<site>` section of my `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\applicationhost.config` and it looks like this:

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Physical path is set to `%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1` which points to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Web Sites`, but in this directory, there are just default files like `iistart.htm`, `iis.png` and other crap.

My site runs on `localhost:58620`, but I there is no site configuration `applicationhost.config` for it.

I start IIS Express from Visual Studio 2015.

So where is the *physical directory* of my `localhost:58620` site located? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your solution folder there is a hidden sub folder called .vs, and an applicationHost.config there controls the things. This is a change in VS 2015.

You can learn more from [this article](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#).